# Random Background Image with a twist - TIED to random SWF elements?

Tags: php, javascript, css, wordpress

I was wondering if it would be possible to do something... basically i have two swf files on a page which interact with each other and then one fullscreen background image - the environment. What i'd like to do is make the background image load randomly from a selection of environments we've created BUT also load the correct corresponding SWF files along with it... i'm not sure if that makes sense but this is currently what it looks like: www.eviltwin.tv

What we want is to have the little girl die in a variety of different ways in different environments, and we want the three things to load connected but randomly, is this possible?

MANY MANY THANKS! :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand the question. But if you want happy.jpg to load with happy.swf and tensed.jpg to load with tensed.swf then you just randomly generate numbers, switch cases and load both files. It would be a lot easier this way

```
<?php
  $mood = rand(1,5);
  switch($mood){
  case '1':
        { echo "<img src='happy.jpg'>"; 
          <object width="810" height="1078" data="Rightside.swf" type="application/x-shockwave-flash"> 
                <param value="http://www.eviltwin.tv/wp/excited.swf" name="movie"> 
                <param value="high" name="quality"> 
                <param value="#ffffff" name="bgcolor"> 
                <param value="true" name="play"> 
                <param value="true" name="loop"> 
                <param value="transparent" name="wmode"> 
                <param value="showall" name="scale"> 
                <param value="true" name="menu"> 
                <param value="false" name="devicefont"> 
                <param value="lt" name="salign"> 
                <param value="sameDomain" name="allowScriptAccess"> 
            <!--<![endif]--> 
                You don't have flash, we won't hold it against you though.
            <!--[if !IE]>--> 
            </object>
            break;}
  case '2':
          {
           echo "<img src='excited.jpg'>"; 
          <object width="810" height="1078" data="excited.swf" type="application/x-shockwave-flash"> 
                <param value="http://www.eviltwin.tv/wp/excited.swf" name="movie"> 
                <param value="high" name="quality"> 
                <param value="#ffffff" name="bgcolor"> 
                <param value="true" name="play"> 
                <param value="true" name="loop"> 
                <param value="transparent" name="wmode"> 
                <param value="showall" name="scale"> 
                <param value="true" name="menu"> 
                <param value="false" name="devicefont"> 
                <param value="lt" name="salign"> 
                <param value="sameDomain" name="allowScriptAccess"> 
            <!--<![endif]--> 
                You don't have flash, we won't hold it against you though.
            <!--[if !IE]>--> 
            </object>
            break;}
```

I hope this gives you an idea. Just got the embed code from you site, so pardon the long code. :)